# How to know if there is a road in the OSM retrieved area

Tags: python, graph, osmnx

I use OSMNX to retrieve driveable road within an area.

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(37.79, 37.78, -122.41, -122.43, network_type='drive')
G_projected = ox.project_graph(G)
ox.plot_graph(G_projected)
```

The bounding box I give may be on a road or on the sea or even in the forest. In order to distinguish between these cases, I would like to know if the reclaimed area contains at least one road. How can I do this?

Comment: You can just look on https://www.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: It would have been simple if it was just a few cases. But, we are talking about several thousand samples.

Comment: If you're trying to automate and scale it, you could put your `graph_from_bbox` call in a try/except block to handle any errors if it cannot create a graph when no elements existed in the query area to download.

Comment: Alright, thank you.